# Windows 2008 R2 Standard Edition random packet drop

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, local-area-network, lag

My dedicated game server running Windows 2008 R2 Standard Edition drops packages randomly and this is causing a freeze for about 1 second for my players.

I have no idea whats causing this.

I've been monitoring the network from the server and also from a client.
My host has also monitored my server and the problem is not on their end, they said that it's my server who is dropping packages just like my MTR result showed me.

I'm in panic mode atm as every time this is happening I loose clients due to lag.

How can I find out what is causing this?

*Sorry for my bad english..*

Comment: Check network MTU settings.  There are tools for analysing MTU discrepancies.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty common with a duplex mismatch with your NIC and Network Switch.  Make sure your NIC for your server and the settings on your network switch are set the same (Auto, 1Gbit Full, etc.)

Comment: Much narrower than bentek's answer.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a variety of reasons for what you are experiencing. Sometimes it's just a simple setting change on your NIC, and other times you will need to do some digging to narrow it down as it may not be obvious.

Here is a quick basic list I put together for you to go through:

- Check logs (eventviewer, etc.) for any events which you can correlate to the times of the drops.
- Review OS configuration (Hardware compatibility, NIC/network settings, etc.).
- Update drivers, firmware, BIOS, and OS patches, if applicable.
- Disable unnecessary services which can take up resources.
- Review need and configuration for any third-party software.